# Get address data of Order

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

This used to work in commerce 1: `{{ order.billingAddress.firstName }}` within a for loop of `craft.orders.all()`.

No longer in Commerce 2. If I use this syntax I get

> Impossible to access an attribute ("firstName") on a null variable.

But when I do: `{{ dump(order.billingAddress) }}` then I see the `firstName` and it is clearly not null:

```
object(craft\commerce\models\Address)#2512 (35) {
  …
  ["firstName"]=> string(6) "Sophie"
  …
}
```

Why can't I access this? Also `| first` doesn't help. I also tried several versions with `customer` or `primaryBillingAddress` as mentioned in the [changes doc](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/changes-in-commerce-2.html#twig-template-changes) But no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that one of the orders in the array of orders has a null billingAddress, and the dump you did was for just one of the orders.

If you are going to access the address `firstName` through the order's billing address, but the address might be null you need to do a check.

You can either do:

```
{% if order.billingAddress %}
 {{ order.billingAddress.firstName }}
{% endif %}
```

Or use the null-coalescing operator in twig:

```
{{ order.billingAddress.firstName ?? '' }}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators

Hope that helps.